# How to ask MathJax to check for tags again when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I need to recall MathJax every time, a button is clicked. How to do that?

I tried using

    `<script type="text/javascript">
        function reloadMathJax() {
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
    }
    </script>`

and calling the function again, but it doesn't work.

It needs to search $$ tags regularly after the button is clicked.

Comment: You need to provide more information on how content is added. Most likely MathJax doesn't find anything because there's nothing new in they page, eg when injecting new content asynchronously.

Comment: I have a text box in which the content is added and displayed using insertAdjacentHtml method.

Comment: A snippet with a minimal example of what you've tried would improve your question.

Comment: You can find the snippet here (https://jsfiddle.net/phk2sxn9/1/) . What wiky.js does is, parses <math></math> tags to $ $ tags.